# Are the command codes for ExecuteMso documented?

Tags: c#, api, ms-office

MS Office apps have an [incredible API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25606634/1294758) that lets one execute any command that is accessible from the UI, but inaccessible from the Object Model. Specifically, you can use [ExecuteMso()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff862419(v=office.15).aspx) to execute any command button, toggle button or split button. The docs say:

> **expression.GetEnabledMso(idMso)**
>
> **idMso** - Identifier for the control (String)

Are the string command codes documented anywhere? Office apps have thousands of unique commands that can be viewed in the Options dialog, and it would be nice to have a reference of the string codes for all of these.

[image: office commands]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are these:

- Office 2007: [Lists of Control IDs](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=3582)
- Office 2010: [Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6627)
- Office 2013: [Office Fluent User Interface Control Identifiers](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=36798)

And see further http://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s2/win003.htm

Answer (score 4):

You can get the ID from the options dialog shown in the question. Hover above any item and find the ID in the tooltip:

[image: MSOID]