# Convert Excel Equation Editor output into a form that can more easily be converted into an Excel Worksheet formula

Tags: excel, vba

I am attempting to convert formulas produced by the Excel Equation Editor to functional Excel cell formulas.  So starting with a formula like: [image: Textbox Formula] I used Selection.Text method and got:
??=  ?? -1.93703+5.334373??  1+ ?? -1.93703+5.334373??  -80.864 ?? 9 +243.06 ?? 8 -228.74 ?? 7 +21.697 ?? 6 +72.108 ?? 5 -21.632 ?? 4 -8.2818 ?? 3 +2.2854 ?? 2 +0.44679??-0.045565
?? 2 =0.971315
where the ?? pairs are a representation of the italic y, e, R, x and minus signs

This code allowed me to figure out what was going on with that:

```
Sub subCheckASCII()
'Select a range or textbox created by excel formula editor and extract the formula from it
'This program developed to start to figure out how to convert output into a functional Excel formula
'Run first time to figure out what the sOutputChar is for each negative AscW and add
'  :sOutputChar = <appropriate translation character> to each Case element

Dim sInput As String
Dim sChar As String
Dim lPos As Long
Dim lLength As Long
Dim sDesc As String
Dim lCorrectUnicode As Long
Dim x As Variant
Dim sOutput As String
Dim sOutputChar As String

Set x = Selection
If VarType(x) = 9 Then   'VarType 9 = Object
    'Text Boxes
    sInput = x.Text
Else
    'Ranges
    sInput = Selection.Text
End If

Debug.Print sInput, Len(sInput)

For lPos = 1 To Len(sInput)
    sChar = Mid(sInput, lPos, 1)
    Select Case AscW(sChar)
    Case -10187: sDesc = vbNullString   '"Surrogate Marker"
    Case -9114: sDesc = "Italic y": sOutputChar = "y"
    Case -9147: sDesc = "Italic R": sOutputChar = "R"
    Case -9115: sDesc = "Italic x": sOutputChar = "x"
    Case -9134: sDesc = "Italic e": sOutputChar = "e"
    Case Is < 0
         MsgBox "Add another Case element to code for " & AscW(sChar)
         Stop
    Case 8722: sDesc = "Minus sign": sOutputChar = "-"
    Case 32: sDesc = "<space>": sOutputChar = " "
    Case 63: sDesc = "Real Question mark": sOutputChar = "?"
    Case Else: sDesc = sChar: sOutputChar = sDesc
    End Select
    sOutput = sOutput & sOutputChar
    Debug.Print lPos, LenB(sChar), sChar, Asc(sChar), AscW(sChar), sDesc
    
    If lPos / 175 = lPos \ 175 Then Stop  'So first lines don't scroll out of Immediate window
Next

Debug.Print "Input:"
Debug.Print sInput
Debug.Print "Output:"
Debug.Print sOutput
```

End Sub

But even after I converted all of the ?? to a more useful form:

From:

??=  ?? -1.93703+5.334373??  1+ ?? -1.93703+5.334373??  -80.864 ?? 9 +243.06 ?? 8 -228.74 ?? 7 +21.697 ?? 6 +72.108 ?? 5 -21.632 ?? 4 -8.2818 ?? 3 +2.2854 ?? 2 +0.44679??-0.045565
?? 2 =0.971315

To:

y=   e -1.93703+5.3343733x  1+  e -1.93703+5.3343733x  -80.864  x 9 +243.06  x 8 -228.74  x 7 +21.697  x 6 +72.108  x 5 -21.632  x 4 -8.2818  x 3 +2.2854  x 2 +0.446799x-0.045565
R 2 =0.971315

Easy to split out the R formula, but there is still a lot of work to be done to convert that string into a functional formula and with the lack of parenthesis in the exponents, I am not sure how I could do it.

Alternately, If I highlight the first row of the text box and copy paste it into a cell, I get:
y=e^(-1.93703+5.334373x)/(1+e^(-1.93703+5.334373x) )-80.864x^9+243.06x^8-228.74x^7+21.697x^6+72.108x^5-21.632x^4-8.2818x^3+2.2854x^2+0.44679x-0.045565

Which has "magically" added parenthesis and carets to indicate exponents.  This I can convert more readily.

I will be dealing with a lot of formulas and would like to automate the import process.  Is there a way to extract the first formula (or even all formulas from the text box) to obtain the second results without manually selecting the contents of the text box?

Answer (score 0):

After more searching I found an answer:
This answer: [Is there any documentation on how to drive the Office "Equation Editor" through VBA in Excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55478312/is-there-any-documentation-on-how-to-drive-the-office-equation-editor-through)
Gave me this command:

`Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso "EquationLinearFormat"`

which converts the Equation Editor professional output into a linear form.

I posted this anyway for general info and to see if others had any other solutions that might be more efficient.